# asp.net HyperLink unable to locate url

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

Below is the asp:HyperLink which the hyperlink wasn't correctly bind:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Go to project" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Project/ProjectMaster.aspx?ProjectID=" + projectID %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Why the hyperlink was disabled (Like the below image) and how to bind URL correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where you use this hyperlink.
If it is a part of the page or user control then it should look like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Go to project" NavigateUrl='~/Project/ProjectMaster.aspx?ProjectID=<%= projectID %>' />
```

If it is a part of repeater or some other template container, then you chould use Eval or Bind methods

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Go to project" NavigateUrl='~/Project/ProjectMaster.aspx?ProjectID=<%# Eval("projectID") %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign some id to hyperlink and give NavigateUrl in code behind. Suppose you have hyperlink id `hlProject`

```
hlProject.NavigateUrl = "~/Project/ProjectMaster.aspx?ProjectID=" + projectID;
```